# Populating Model List property with user input

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Consider following mode class -

```
public class UserLakshya
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public List<Barrier> Barriers { get; set; }
}

public class Barrier
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

While generating view for `UserLakshya` model, I do not get template to insert Barrier properties, (say Comments). I tried following -

1. Create a partial view for Barrier Type.
2. Render this partial view in the main view as below -

   @Html.Partial("Barrier", Model.Barriers)

I need help to create view layout for Barriers list so that list of barriers is bound directly to the instance of `UserLakshya`. Is it possible ?

I referred [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) but this seem to be helpful only `for displaying populated list items to the view`. I am looking for the vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand.

If your view is strongly typed, say

```
@model UserLakshya
```

then you can do

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Title)
@foreach (var barrier in Model.Barriers) {
     @Html.DisplayFor(m => barrier.Comments)
}
```

or a for loop (needed for edition)

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Barriers.Count; i++) {
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Barriers[i].Comments)
}
```

Comment: This seems definitely easier than creating `separate partial view`, Only side-effect I see is, `we must` initialize the list to at least one item so that control goes inside for loop.

Comment: This is inevitable I think.